# For which values of $n$ (natural number) is $(x^n)-1$ divisible by $(x^2)+1$

Tags: abstract-algebra

For which values of a natural number $n$ is

$(x^n)-1$ divisible by $(x^2)+1$ ?

Answer (score 3):

The polynomial $x^2+1=(x-i)(x+i)$ divides $P(x)=x^n-1$ iff its roots $\pm i$ are also roots of $P$ so
$$P(i)=i^n-1=P(-i)=(-i)^n-1=0\iff n=4p$$

Comment: the first bit makes sense splitting into complex numbers however how does n=4p, what is p in this case

Comment: $p\in \Bbb N$. Try to calculate $P(i)$ and $P(-i)$ in the cases: $n=4p,4p+1,4p+2,4p+3$. What do you find?

Comment: p is any positive integer (that is, $p\in\mathbb{Z}^+$) -- for what kinds of integers does $i^n=1$?

Answer (score 0):

For any polynomial $\mathrm{p}$, the [Factor Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_theorem) says that $x-a$ divides $\mathrm{p}$ if, and only if, $\mathrm{p}(a)=0$.

For $x^2+1$ to divide $\mathrm{p}$, we need both $x-\mathrm{i}$ and $x+\mathrm{i}$ to divide $\mathrm{p}$ since notice that $x^2+1 \equiv (x+\mathrm{i})(x-\mathrm{i})$.

The [Factor Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_theorem) tells us that $x^2+1$ divides $\mathrm{p}$ if, and only if, $\mathrm{p}(\mathrm{i}) = \mathrm{p}(-\mathrm{i}) = 0$.

Let $\mathrm{p}(x) = x^n-1$. Consider separately the cases where $n$ is even and odd.

If $n$ is even then $\mathrm{p}(x) = x^{2k}-1$. It follows that
$$\mathrm{p}(\pm\mathrm{i}) = (\pm\mathrm{i})^{2k}-1=\left((\pm\mathrm{i})^2\right)^k-1=(-1)^k-1$$
Hence, $\mathrm{p}(\pm\mathrm{i}) = 0$ if, and only if, $k$ is even, i.e. $n=2k$ is divisible by $4$.

If $n$ is odd then $\mathrm{p}(x) = x^{2k+1}-1$. It follows that
$$\mathrm{p}(\pm\mathrm{i}) = (\pm\mathrm{i})^{2k+1}-1=(\pm\mathrm{i})(\pm\mathrm{i})^{2k}-1 = (\pm\mathrm{i})(-1)^k-1$$
This has non-zero real part for all $k$, and so $\mathrm{p}(\pm\mathrm{i}) \neq 0$ for all odd $n$.

It follows that $x^2+1$ divides $x^n-1$ if, and only if, $n$ is divisible by $4$.